# Crear Div en página aspx .NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Tengo una función que devuelve un DATASET, pero esa información me gustaría imprimirla en la página de aspx.
Esta es la función

```
public DataSet filtrarFaq(eFaq entidad)
        {
            DataSet d = new DataSet();
            try
            {
                SqlConnection s = conn.Connection;
                SqlDataAdapter datos;
                com.Connection = s;
                com.CommandText = "prod_filtroFaq";
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@pregunta",SqlDbType.NVarChar,50));
                com.Parameters["@pregunta"].Value=entidad.pregunta;
                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@categoriaFolio",SqlDbType.Int));
                com.Parameters["@categoriaFolio"].Value =entidad.categoria ;
                com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sitioFolio",SqlDbType.Int));
                com.Parameters["@sitioFolio"].Value = entidad.sitio;
                datos = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
                datos.Fill(d);
            }catch(SqlException ex){
                string msj = ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                com.Parameters.Clear();
                com.Connection.Close();
            }
            return d;
        }
```

Pero ahora quisiera imprimir la información del dataset en DIV en la pagina aspx

Comment: Ernesto, debes especificar que problema tienes al implementar la solución de tu problema. Si buscas ideas, recomendaciones o consejos es mejor que uses Google. Si explicar un problema concreto incluye un __[mcve]__ que lo ilustre.

Answer (score 1):

crea en tu formulario un control de tipo literal

```
<asp:Literal id="myLiteral" runat=server  text="" />
```

y desde tu codigo lo puedes usar asi:

```
myLiteral.Text="<div>" + aqui coloca lo que quieras... + "</div>";
```

Y listo! la ventaja del literal es que te puede interpresar codigo html.
En tu caso debes recorrer el data set...asi:

```
string contenido ="<div>";
foreach(DataRow dr in tuDataset.Table[0].Rows)
{
  contenido += "<ul><li>";
  contenido += dr[0].ToString();
  contenido += "</li></ul>";
}
myLiteral.Text = contenido;
```

Comment: Ok, lo voy a intentar, gracias

Comment: Pero si yo quiero recorrer el dataset para imprimir los datos en componentes HTML?